# How to add a contribute page

Tags: custom-post-types

I have to create a crowdfunding theme. I have created a Post Types by name ‘Projects’.

The permalink of my project is`http://www.example.com/project/my-first-project`. I have created a Pledge Now button on this page. My question is that when this button is clicked it should redirect the site to `http://www.example.com/project/my-first-project/contribute` page and display the stuff like the title, content,etc of the previous page i.e. `my-first-project` page.

How to do?

Comment: If you are having troubles with developing a Crowdfunding site yourself, I can suggest using plugins such as the [Orion CMS plugin](https://www.thrinacia.com/orion). It works great on Wordpress websites. Using these types of tools can be a real time saver. Hope this helps!